# UISwipeGestureRecognizer UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged not called

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I'm define two `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` in my application:

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeLeftVolume = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]  initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeGestureVolume:)];
swipeLeftVolume.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
[self.playerView addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeftVolume];

UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRightVolume = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]  initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeGestureVolume:)];
swipeRightVolume.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
[self.playerView addGestureRecognizer:swipeRightVolume];
```

In the target method i have 3 states:

```
UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan
UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged
UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded
```

and i noticed that only the `UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded` is called.

Any idea what can be the problem? i want to recognize a swipe on specific `UIView` :

```
- (void)handleSwipeGestureVolume:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        NSLog(@"Start");
    } else if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
        NSLog(@"Changed");
    } else if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        NSLog(@"Finish");
    }
}
```

Comment: [self.playerView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];  //add this line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you enable UserInteraction for **self.playerView**.

Answer (score 2):

Seem like you are confused between `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` and `UIPanGestureRecognizer`.

*`UISwipeGestureRecognizer` will generate `UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded` state only* while `UIPanGestureRecognizer` has both 3 states you want.

If you need to receive both `UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan`, `UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged`, `UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded`, use `UIPanGestureRecognizer` instead.

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]  initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeGestureVolume:)];
[self.playerView addGestureRecognizer:panGesture];
```

Answer (score 0):

For any gesture recogniser, user interaction must be enabled to work. Without it none of the gestures will be triggered including `touchBegan:`, `touchMove:`, etc.

so you need to make `[self.playerView setUserInteractionEnabled:TRUE];`

And one more thing I would like to let you know that if you have implemented `touchBegan:`, `touchMove:`, etc. then the method will be triggered first for gesture rather than `UIGestureRecognizer` shilds.